# Attempt to get length of null array - byte[] array

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, navigation-drawer

Estoy creando una aplicación con la opción de navigationDrawer en Android Studio, también estoy trabajando con SQLite.

El problema es que cuando trato de mostrar 5 elementos guardados en la vista del recycler, la aplicación se crashea. NOTA: Algo interesante, es que cuando reinstalé la aplicación, el recycler me permitió mostrar 5 elementos, pero se crasheo en el sexto elemento. Luego, volví a instalar la aplicación y el recycler me permitió mostrar 6 elementos, pero se bloqueó en el séptimo elemento, y así sucesivamente.

Aquí está el código fuente del fragmento donde estoy usando el recyclerView:

```
public class TreesFragment extends Fragment {
private FragmentTreesBinding binding;

private ConexionSQLiteHelper conn;
private RecyclerView rvTrees;
private FloatingActionButton fab;
private RecyclerTreesAdapter adapter;

ArrayList<Arbol> listaTrees;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trees, container, false);

    conn = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(getContext(), UtilidadesArbol.DB_NAME, null, 1);

    listaTrees = new ArrayList<>();

    rvTrees = vista.findViewById(R.id.rvTrees);

    getData();

    rvTrees.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    rvTrees.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    adapter = new RecyclerTreesAdapter(listaTrees);
    rvTrees.setAdapter(adapter);

    fab = vista.findViewById(R.id.fabToRegisterTree);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityTreeRegister.class));
        }
    });

    return vista;
}

//THIS IS THE METHOD THAT LOADS ALL THE DATA IN THE RECYCLER VIEW
public void getData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();
    byte[] imgBytes;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + UtilidadesArbol.TREES_TABLE_NAME, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        String treeName = cursor.getString(0);
        String treeScientificName = cursor.getString(1);
        String treeDescription = cursor.getString(2);
        imgBytes = cursor.getBlob(3);

        Bitmap obj = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.length);

        listaTrees.add(new Arbol(treeName, treeScientificName, treeDescription, obj));
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getData();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    binding = null;
}
}
```

Aqui esta mi clase modelo:

```
public class Arbol {
private String treeName;
private String treeScientificName;
private String treeDescription;
private Bitmap treeImg;

public Arbol() {
}

public Arbol(String treeName, String treeScientificName, String treeDescription, Bitmap treeImg) {
    this.treeName = treeName;
    this.treeScientificName = treeScientificName;
    this.treeDescription = treeDescription;
    this.treeImg = treeImg;
}

public String getTreeName() {
    return treeName;
}

public void setTreeName(String treeName) {
    this.treeName = treeName;
}

public String getTreeScientificName() {
    return treeScientificName;
}

public void setTreeScientificName(String treeScientificName) {
    this.treeScientificName = treeScientificName;
}

public String getTreeDescription() {
    return treeDescription;
}

public void setTreeDescription(String treeDescription) {
    this.treeDescription = treeDescription;
}

public Bitmap getTreeImg() {
    return treeImg;
}

public void setTreeImg(Bitmap treeImg) {
    this.treeImg = treeImg;
}
}
```

El ERROR MESSAGE:

[image]

```
Process: com.example.testnavdrwer, PID: 13694
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at com.example.acplite.ui.trees.TreesFragment.getData(TreesFragment.java:92)
        at com.example.acplite.ui.trees.TreesFragment.onCreateView(TreesFragment.java:60)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2106)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1139)
```

Este es el método donde la aplicación obtiene el error. Cuando depuro la aplicación, el ** bytes ** array obtiene el valor null justo cuando "excedo" los elementos del recyclerView como escribí al principio.

[image]

La linea de codigo especifica donde se bugea:

```
        Bitmap obj = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.length);
```

Y el código con el que guardo el árbol:

```
// METODO PARA GUARDAR UN ARBOL
    public void storeTree(Arbol obj){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Bitmap imageToStore = obj.getTreeImg();

        outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        imageToStore.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
        imageBytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(UtilidadesArbol.CAMPO_NOMBRE, obj.getTreeName());
        values.put(UtilidadesArbol.CAMPO_NOMBRE_CIENTIFICO, obj.getTreeScientificName());
        values.put(UtilidadesArbol.CAMPO_DESCRIPCION, obj.getTreeDescription());
        values.put(UtilidadesArbol.CAMPO_IMAGEN, imageBytes);

        long cantidad = db.insert(UtilidadesArbol.TREES_TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        if( cantidad != 0 ){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Image added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.close();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "ERROR: Image not added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

He tratado de resolverlo pero estoy atorado en esto. :(

Comment: Primero que nada, el código y los errores son ***TEXTO***, por favor, trátalos como tal y no como imágenes! Segundo... el error te está diciendo que el tamaño de la imagen es muy grande y está devolviendo `null`. Esto pasa porque el cursor tiene un límite de tamaño en lo que puede devolverte (2MB si no recuerdo mal). Lo normal es guardar la imagen en el almacenamiento del dispositivo y guardar la ***RUTA*** en la base de datos. Recuerda que sqLITE es... bueno, *lite*. Es una base de datos bastante modesta, no se le puede pedir que trabaje como un SQL Server!

Comment: Agrega por favor como estas guardando la imagen, ahí debe ser el problema.

Answer (score 0):

El error que obtienes es debido a que no hay información guardada en el campo, por lo tanto la variable `imgBytes` que es un byte array tiene valor null:

```
 imgBytes = cursor.getBlob(3);
 Bitmap obj = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.length);
```

Debes asegurar que estas guardando la información de la imagen correctamente.

Comment: Si, se que no estoy guardando nada pero ese es el problema, no se pq no estoy guardando nada. Solamente no me guarda nada en la ultima posicion del array y lo que no guarda es la columna foto.